# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "matches" does not exist

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, virtual-machine, git-bash

I'm trying to do a final 'tournament' project in intro to relational databases course by udacity. Here's a link to the project's description:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/16IgOm4XprTaKxAa8w02y028oBECOoB1EI1ReddADEeY/pub?embedded=true

I've got a file titled tournament.sql in which database 'tournament' and two tables 'matches' and 'players' are defined:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS tournament;

CREATE DATABASE tournament;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS matches (

id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
player1 integer references players (id),
player2 integer references players (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS players (

id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(40)
);
```

I also defined bodies of two functions deleteMatches and deletePlayers in tournament.py file:

```
import psycopg2

def connect():
"""Connect to the PostgreSQL database. Returns a database connection."""
return psycopg2.connect("dbname=tournament")

def deleteMatches():
"""Remove all the match records from the database."""
conn = connect()
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE matches;")
conn.commit()
conn.close()

def deletePlayers():
"""Remove all the player records from the database."""
conn = connect()
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE players;")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

There's one more python file predefined/prebuilt by the author of the whole course 'tournament_test.py', which can be executed to check if all required functions in tournament.py work fine/do their job. That file 'tournament_test.py' is executed in Virtual Machine from command line and in my case produces following error:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:/vagrant/tournament$ python tournament_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tournament_test.py", line 151, in 
testCount()
File "tournament_test.py", line 17, in testCount
deleteMatches()
File "/vagrant/tournament/tournament.py", line 16, in deleteMatches
c.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE matches;")
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "matches" does not exist
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code? I'm starting to lose patience. I've spent several hours trying to figure out, what's wrong and I can find any information that would be helpful. This course is so bad, sloppy and unprofessional. I just can't find right words to express my frustration.

Comment: Did you load that SQL file into the database? How?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does it mean to load  SQL file into the database? Which database you mean? How should i load sql files into databases? Do you mean this: "from tournament import * " which is the top part of the predefined python file tournament_test.py?

Comment: Well what are you expecting a file on its own to do? It's all very well writing a file of SQL commands, but unless you actually give them to the database you might as well have written nursery rhymes. Your error is telling you that you haven't created the table, which is true if you've never actually run that file.

Comment: If you mean this by loading tournament.sql into psql :vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:/vagrant/tournament$ psql < tournament.sql . It doesn't work either, as python interpreter returns the very same error:  psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "matches" does not exist

Answer (score 1):

"You probably already solved this on your own like I had to, however if you are still searching or for anyone else who may come across this thread. I am also taking this course and came across this beginner problem.

This was user error. I was connecting to vagrant and the tournament database in the wrong way.

After logging into vagrant I was in the right folder accessing the right database but in the wrong method.

Error:

Once in vagrant I went to psql as user vagrant and imported the file.

```
\i tournament.sql
```

Then I connected to the database.

```
\c tournament
```

Then I was exiting psql to run the file and getting the relation does not exist error.

I needed to do one more step.

FIX:

Once connected and logged into the database tournament. I needed to import the tournament.sql file again.

That created the relations within the actual database and not just vagrant or wherever I was creating them before.

so from Vagrant after the command Vagrant ssh
    # run these commands separately 
    cd /vagrant/tournament/

```
psql

\i tournament.sql

\c tournament

\i tournament

#last check to verify your relations were created
\dt
\d (table or view)
```

That is what did it for me. The rest of the project was easy. I hope this helps anyone searching for the answer on here." [My q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46679910/python-backed-sql-database-returning-a-psycopg2-programmingerror-relation-does)